# Slow performance of System.Math library in .NET4/VS2010

Tags: .net, performance, .net-3.5, .net-4.0, visual-studio-2010

My application compiled in .NET 4 seems to be performing really slow compared to .NET 3.5. When I did the performance analysis, I found out that the System.Math libraries in VS2010/.NET 4 have slowed down considerably.

Any explanation to this? Has anyone else come across this or am I the only one seeing this?

UPDATE:

My sample code looks like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 1000000; j++)
        {
            Min((double) ((j + 1) / 2), (double) ((j + 2) / 2));
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < 1000000; k++)
        {
            Min((double) ((k + 2) / 2), (double) ((k + 3) / 2));
        }
        for (int m = 0; m < 1000000; m++)
        {
            Min((double) ((m + 3) / 2), (double) ((m + 4) / 2));
        }
        for (int n = 0; n < 1000000; n++)
        {
            Min((double) ((n + 4) / 2), (double) ((n + 5) / 2));
        }
    }
```

The above code takes 0.55 seconds in framework 3.5. The same takes 0.8 seconds in .NET 4. Similar performance issues I have seen in other functions also like Truncate, Floor and Max amongst others.

Thanks,
Niranjan

Comment: Show real numbers please, point to specific functions it is interesting to analyze.

Comment: What methods are you calling? With what input? How do you time them?

Comment: Does your real application do 40 million basic math operations in a loop?

Comment: It is not exactly 40 million that we use, but we do use considerably high number. we have set of graphs which do plotting and stuff like that.. so the hit count of these functions is large!

Comment: Your benchmark is too simple.  A sufficiently clever JIT compiler could throw away everything you've computed there and take 0 seconds.  At least accumulate a checksum of the answers (i.e. `sum += Min...`).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small test program taking your code (with minor changes to add up the results of Min) so that JIT does not optimise the memory image of the code. Also I compiled using /o+ flag for csc. I used all the three versions of csc I had on my machine (2.0/3.5/4.0).

Results: No major differences. All took between 165-175 milliseconds in a few runs for each assembly. These fluctutations could be because of any other background noise in your system, so I will not rely on such micro-benchmarks.

In your system, I am pretty sure you would see fluctuations of times even when running the same assembly for micro-benchmarks like this.

Vijay